# why won't my code process in PHP?

Tags: php, html, json, curl

I'm super new to this area. for some reason when I put the > symbol anywhere in the code, every bit of code after it is shown as text in the browser. I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Site Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
$curl = curl_init("https://xboxapi.com/v2/messages");
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-AUTH: key';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';


$data = array(
    "to" => "{user}",
    "message" => "test"
);

$json = json_encode($data);


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);



$server_output = curl_exec ($curl);

curl_close ($curl);

print  $server_output
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What `>` symbol? Where do you put it?

Comment: Oh I removed it and put = instead of => i'll edit it.

Comment: @u_mulder      ...forgot to mention you.

Comment: Well I'm really clueless as to why its doing this: was I supposed to install anything besides notepad++ and cURL?

Comment: Is this saved as a php file? Are you viewing it on a live server and not as a local file? If everything after a `>` is showing in the browser it tells you that it thinks `<?php` is a html tag, not a php tag.

Comment: I'm not experiencing the issue you describe with this code.  However, one thing to be aware of is '=>' is how we set or access the value of an associative array.  Changing it to an equal sign is not going to resolve your problem

Comment: Thank you all for your help i think i got it figured out!

Comment: Care to share how you `got it figured out`? Did the answer below help, if so mark it as answered? Or if it was something else, share what you found for future readers of this question.

Answer (score 1):

This would not look great as a comment, so I'm posting here what I got when running the code in a CLI/shell.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Site Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
```

> ```
>     {"success":false,"error_code":401,
> "error_message":"No API Key provided or invalid API Key"}
> ```

If I run it using PHP Built In web server..I get

`{"success":false,"error_code":401,"error_message":"No API Key provided or invalid API Key"}`

Per https://xboxapi.com/documentation if you send a valid user id and key in the header, it should work.